# javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not found

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm learning backend development with quarkus and I wanted to implement hibernate with postgresql.

When I add these 2 dependencies in gradle.

```
implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache")
implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-postgresql")
```

it throws me the following error:

```
Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.narayana.jta.deployment.NarayanaJtaProcessor#build threw an exception: javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not found
    at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.arjuna.common.util.propertyservice.PropertiesFactoryStax.loadFromXML(PropertiesFactoryStax.java:46)
    at com.arjuna.common.util.propertyservice.AbstractPropertiesFactory.loadFromFile(AbstractPropertiesFactory.java:150)
    at com.arjuna.common.util.propertyservice.AbstractPropertiesFactory.getPropertiesFromFile(AbstractPropertiesFactory.java:102)
    at com.arjuna.common.util.propertyservice.AbstractPropertiesFactory.initDefaultProperties(AbstractPropertiesFactory.java:196)
    at com.arjuna.common.util.propertyservice.AbstractPropertiesFactory.getDefaultProperties(AbstractPropertiesFactory.java:62)
    at com.arjuna.common.util.propertyservice.PropertiesFactory.getDefaultProperties(PropertiesFactory.java:48)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.deployment.NarayanaJtaProcessor.build(NarayanaJtaProcessor.java:124)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:909)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:282)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
```

Checking other posts, it seems that there's a conflict in the dependencies, one dependency might be using a library with a lower version and another with a higher version.
Therefore some version doesn't have this `Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not found` or that's what I understood.

Does anyone have any idea? I've spent like 5h trying multiple solutions, however I'm still in the exact same starting point... I wonder what I'm missing

quarkus version: `3.1.2.Final`

kotlin version: `1.8.10`

Here's my `build.gradle.kts` dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation(enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}"))

    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-arc")

    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-cache") // Local cache in-memory

    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson")

    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client-reactive")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson")

    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-postgresql")

    testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5")
    testImplementation("io.rest-assured:rest-assured")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that just providing this dependency: `implementation("com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:6.5.1")` removes the issue